# Best way to add a method to an oracle-made java class

Tags: java, buttongroup

I have created a method for getting the text from a selected radio button when I pass it the buttongroup it's in. I've been reading that helper/utility classes might not be the best idea because they can turn into god classes, which I can see happening after a while. Plus, I'm only adding one method and that method is very specific to buttons.

So my question is, is there a best way to add a method to a class that oracle made? I would like this method to always be available whenever I make a new project and use buttongroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass that contains your new method.

Inheritance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: So if I wanted to make a JRadioButton then I would have to use the subclass name I made if I wanted that method to be available?

Comment: @tazboy Yes, if I am understanding you correctly. Once you create a class that `extend`s JRadioButton and add your method to this new class, you should use your new class instead of the old one.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. I actually extended ButtonGroup. No issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to add methods to [`JRadioButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JRadioButton.html)? You cannot do that. The typical way this is done is by `extending JRadioButton`, add the method and use that class everywhere.